# Google Sign-in for iOS swift error: bridging header '...path/myProject/myProject/myProject-Bridging-Header.h' does not exist

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-signin

I followed all the instructions on [Google Sign-in for iOS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating) using CocoaPods (even though I hadn't used CocoaPods before and still don't really understand what it is) and I am getting this error when I run the program:

> bridging header
>   '...path/myProject/myProject/myProject-Bridging-Header.h' does not
>   exist

I made sure that my header file is in the right place and everything. Any help?

UPDATE:

I tried deleting the whole project and following the steps over and I realized that when I typed `pod 'Google/SignIn'` it said `[!] Unknown command: 'Google/SignIn'`.

Is this step somehow the reason why the bridging header has an error?

Comment: Delete it and add it again and make sure you see it inside your build settings.

Comment: I did, but it came up with the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my own problem and I thought I should put my answer so if anyone has the same problem they don't have to lose sleep over it.

The reason that the bridging header was coming up with an error was because the `Google/SignIn` wasn't linked in the Podfile. Instead of following Google's steps in the "Set up your CocoaPod dependencies" section of [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating) page, I followed the steps from [CocoaPods Guides - Using CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html) to link the pod.

The main step (the one that I don't think happened last time) was this:

> Add a CocoaPod by specifying pod '$PODNAME' on a single line inside your target block [of your Podfile].

The last step from here is to...

> Open the MyApp.xcworkspace that was created. This should be the file you use everyday to create your app.

so ya... hope that helps somebody